# Does apple allow you to send self captured crash logs on launch of the app without notifying the user?

Tags: ios

Currently we are capturing the crash exceptions and logging it to a local file. On launch of the app we will send those log files back to our own server.

My question: Is it allowed by apple to retrieve user's crashing logs without notifying the user? Do we have to display a dialog to let the user choose whether to send it or not?

Thanks

Comment: Whether Apple allows it or not it is always good policy to be upfront with users. Let them tell you what they are willing to send you. Give them the choice the first time you detect a crash report. If they say "Never" then don't bug them again and don't send the log in secret.

Comment: Agree with @rmaddy, but to answer your question plainly, there's nothing in Apple's terms that requires you to display a dialog when sending data from your own app to your own server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [standard EULA](https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/appstore/dev/stdeula/) that is applied when you add your App to the store contains the following clause:

> b. Consent to Use of Data: You agree that Application Provider may collect and use technical data and related information, including but not limited to technical information about Your device, system and application software, and peripherals, that is gathered periodically to facilitate the provision of software updates, product support and other services to You (if any) related to the Licensed Application. Application Provider may use this information, as long as it is in a form that does not personally identify You, to improve its products or to provide services or technologies to You.

You need to consider whether the crash information may contain personally identifying information, in which case you may need to supply an alternate EULA or seek permission within the application

Comment: Hi, do you have a link to the reference you posted here? Thanks

Comment: The standard EULA is available here - https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/appstore/dev/stdeula/